# How can i share an object among different pages in browser?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, popup, session-storage

I have been given a task in which `PageA` opens a link in new window and when user navigates from `PageA` to `PageB` then `PageB` should be able to access that `new window` object created by `PageA`.

Since I am new to Frontend world, so I have very limited solution in my mind, I have tried

1. **sessionStorage** - This failed since while storing sessionStorage casts the object as String and on `pageB` I was getting stringified form of object i.e `[object Window]`.
2. **Window** - Storing `new window` object in `window`, this also failed since when i moved to `PageB` then content of `window` were flushed and re-assigned.

Can someone suggest me some way to achieve this ?

Comment: Can you please share your code !

Comment: Couldn't you pass the object as a JSON string?